# how to convert a string into julian date in python

Tags: python, string, date, julian-date

My table a field is format like "8192009", type is string. I need to convert it into julian date. Like how many days in a year.
I have tried

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_object=datetime.strptime("8192009","%b%d%Y")
```

it gives me ValueError: time data '8192009' does not match format '%b%d%Y'

Comment: you are not missing a digit?

Comment: @CactusWoman it is different problem. Because right now i cannot even convert this string into datetime.

Comment: strptime token `%b` looks for abbreviated month names as in Jan, Feb, etc. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior shows all the token behaviors so look for one that you want

Comment: @LetzerWille what digit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
>>> date_object=datetime.strptime("Aug192009","%b%d%Y")
>>> date_object
datetime.datetime(2009, 8, 19, 0, 0)
>>>
```

or this:

```
>>> date_object=datetime.strptime("8192009","%m%d%Y")
>>> date_object
datetime.datetime(2009, 8, 19, 0, 0)
>>>
```